# flask fetch mysql without refreshing page

Tags: python, mysql, flask

i am just getting started into python and flask (for the raspberry pi). I want a web application that show data from mysql without refreshing page i have tried this

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'raspberry'
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'tesdb'
    mysql = MySQL(app)


    @app.route('/')
    def interactive():
        return render_template('interactive.html')
    @app.route('/ambildata')
    def ambildata():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT*FROM contoh WHERE id = 1''')
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return jsonify(result = result)
```

interactive.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function (data) {
              $("#result").text(data.result);
          }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='container'>


    <p id=result></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

but i can't see the data from the webpage

Comment: Where do you visit "/ambildata" in your javascript code?

Comment: i  confuse how to connect the flask and javascript

Comment: If you do not want to reload the page you will want to look into an option like Angular.js or React.js. You can always use JQuery.ajax() but your code needs to call the route.

Comment: thx,solved using ajax